# How to scroll views whithn view in android?

Tags: android, layout

What I want to do is to scroll view after listening a button.
Simply user taps button and view is scrolled to specific id below.

I tried to use scrollto and scrollby passing as an argument reference to object to which I want to scroll with no effect.

Anyone solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent many hours on this.

Try something like this. It makes sure that the item selected it the one in view:

`ListView listView;

int positionSelected = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
listView.setSelection(positionSelected);`